# How do I create watermark directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple application that uses a jquery to watermark textboxes. I have authored a very simple directive to use that watermark so I can apply it to input elements but it is not working. If I stop the debugger I can see the watermark being added. However, by the time the UI is finished loading the watermark is gone.

```
app.directive('ngWatermark', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
            debugger
            $elem.watermark(attrs.ngWatermark);
        }
    }
});
```

Markup code to use directive.

```
<input ng-watermark="Search Companies" />
```

This seems like it should work but I haven't had any luck yet. Can anyone fill me in on where I might be going wrong?

I have also noticed now that if I give the textbox focus and leave again the watermark appears as expected.

Finally, I can get the expected behavior with a setTimeout in the directive but I would rather an explanation of what is going on internally.

```
// HACK that makes it work
... 
setTimeout(function() { $elem.watermark(attrs.ngWatermark); }, 10);
```

Comment: I don't know about AngularJS, but is there a reason you couldn't use the HTML5 placeholder attribute? https://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Comment: Actually, I am not up to date with HTML 5 but that sounds perfect. It would useful to understand though.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your directive is executed before the DOM element is fully rendered. Depending on the inner working of `watermark` JQuery plugin, it cannot make the change effective at this stage.

The execution is postponed until the JS get a breathing space at DOM completion when you use `$timeout`.

Please see [this](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering/) article for an example.